# User with builtin "read" role still able to write/update documents in mongodb 5.0.8

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB v5.0.8 running with multiple databases. I switched to the required database **(leaderboard-db)** and added in a new user using the following commands from mongo shell:

Switched to the required DB:

`use leaderboard-db`

and

Created new user:

`db.createUser({ user: "aa", pwd: "leaderboardadmin#@!", roles: [ { role: "read", db: "leaderboard-db" } ], mechanisms: [ "SCRAM-SHA-256" ]})`

Got success in user creation and can verify it by command

`show users`

Response:

```
{
                "_id" : "leaderboard-db.aa",
                "userId" : UUID("f571db84-cae4-4aac-b2f9-83b57094dd1b"),
                "user" : "aa",
                "db" : "leaderboard-db",
                "roles" : [
                        {
                                "role" : "read",
                                "db" : "leaderboard-db"
                        }
                ],
                "mechanisms" : [
                        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
                ]
        }
```

I then use Studio 3T to connect to MongoDB with the user "aa". I should only be able to read the documents in the **(leaderboard-db)**; however, I can also modify the document.

[Screenshot of updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izN39.png)

Can anyone help resolve this, please?

I want to only allow the reading of documents for the user "aa". User "aa" should not have write access.

Thanks

Jack

Comment: How do you connect? Did you specify authentication database `leaderboard-db`? Check user and role with `db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 }).authInfo`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I connect from Studio 3T and I ran the command ```db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 }).authInfo``` , got the following result:

{
 "authenticatedUsers" : [
  {
   "user" : "aa",
   "db" : "leaderboard-db"
  }
 ],
 "authenticatedUserRoles" : [
  {
   "role" : "read",
   "db" : "leaderboard-db"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: What's the command and do you get an error when you **execute** the update?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I simply use the Studio3T UI tool to update the document and it updates successfully. But I can also run the following command to issue the update: db.getCollection("players").update({ _id : ObjectId("62b8dc28de75f39d1b2b31e1")},{ $set : { "name" : "Test Update" } }) However, since this is a read-only user, it should not be able to modify!

Comment: Did you enable authentication? Check with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  I see the no mention of Authentication in the response when I run ```db.serverCmdLineOpts()```. Following that, I reviewed /etc/mongod.conf and Auth =  true was commented out. If I remove the comment and restart mongod, it fails to start. If I comment it back again, mongod starts up all good.

Comment: What means "it fails to start"? Any error message? Obviously without authentication enabled, every user has full access to entire database.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks a ton, your recommendations helped resolve the problem. Authentication was apparently not enabled inside of /etc/mongod.conf And when I enabled, MongoDB service was failing to start. Reason was that the Security section content inside of /etc/mongod.conf was not indented correctly resulting in parse failure of the config. After I sorted that, the MongoDB service restarted and also the updates failed due to improper permissions. So that worked like a charm! Appreciate your help again. Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per recommendations from @WernfriedDomscheit, I was required to enable Authentication. I did that by updating the `/etc/mongod.conf` file, uncommented the `Security` section, added `Authorization: enabled` and restarting MongoDB by `service mongod restart`

That sorted it all and I was able to create users with different role-based access.

Life is good again.